# Where can i find req.isAuthenticated() function in MEAN.JS?

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, meanjs

I am using MEAN.JS but i can't able to find req.isAuthenticated() function in that MEAN.JS. please check this link

https://github.com/meanjs/mean/releases/tag/v0.3.3

i am using same code for learning please some one help me out...

Comment: "Can't find" in what regard? Can you be a bit more specific about what issue it is you're having?

Comment: It is middleware provided by **passport** library - https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/6bc59cb329ec1aebc028423d304b3f34f8112e60/lib/http/request.js#L91

Comment: I have installed MEAN.JS and i am using only server side code .i am not using front end angular code .

I am using different servers. for frontend(client side) i am maintaining one serve, for backend(server side) i am using MEAN.JS .

Signup and Signin is working fine but when i create article i am getting error

"User is not logged in" how can i solve this .please some one help me out. -Joe Clay

Comment: thanks @ Krzysztof Safjanowski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it on git hub. https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/a892b9dc54dce34b7170ad5d73d8ccfba87f4fcf/lib/passport/http/request.js#L74

```
req.isAuthenticated = function() {
  var property = 'user';
  if (this._passport && this._passport.instance._userProperty) {
    property = this._passport.instance._userProperty;
  }
return (this[property]) ? true : false;
};
```

P.S.: I just noticed that the link has already been provided in the comment section. Still, I am going to leave the answer here for quick reference of the function